# Magento 2 : How to Display Cart Price Rule on Product Page?

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules, product-page

I started in **Magento 2** a week ago and don't know much about it, I created a **Cart Price Rule** named `"10% billet discount"` that is applied in a few items, with specific attributes.

I want to display this Rule on specific products page that the rule is applied. There is a way that I can do that?

Comment: Welcome, to Magento StackExchange. I think you need to create a `catalog price rule` for that.

Comment: i thought that too, but i can't set one condition for payment method (billet) in catalog price rule.

Comment: Has anybody any ideas how to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Wreite on code product listing page or product details page.

```
                                  $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                                  $rules = $objectManager->create('Magento\SalesRule\Model\RuleFactory')->create();
                                  $rules=$rules->getCollection();
                                  $objDate = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime');
                                  $_currentTime = strtotime($objDate->date());
                                  foreach ($rules as $rule) {
                                        $fromDate = $rule->getFromDate();
                                        $toDate = $rule->getToDate();
                                        if (isset($fromDate) && $_currentTime >= strtotime($fromDate)) {
                                            if (isset($toDate)) {
                                                if (strtotime($toDate) >= $_currentTime) {



                                                $product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($_product->getId());
                                                $item = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
                                                $item->setProduct($product);
                                                if ($rule->getActions()->validate($item)) {
                                                    $product_label=$rule->getName();
                                                    break;
                                                }

                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }

                        if($product_label)
                            echo '<div class="product-labels">'.$product_label.'</div>';
```